# How to i can access to one of multi sheets in a spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets-api

I'm newbie, i developing small project import csv to google sheets, 
about part import csv to google sheets and create a sheet in spreadsheets i successed. How i can access to sheet that i created? Under is code to i create a sheet in spreadsheet ID. Thanks!!

```
$client = getClient();
$service = new Google_Service_Sheets($client);
$valueInputOption = 'USER_ENTERED';

$spreadsheetId = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxSPREADSHEETIDxxxxxxxxxx';

$title = date('m-d');

$body = new Google_Service_Sheets_BatchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest(array( 'requests' => array('addSheet' => array('properties' => array('title' => $title )))));

$result = $service->spreadsheets->batchUpdate($spreadsheetId, $body);
```

Answer (score 0):

The way of accessing the data of the google spreadsheets is as below:

```
/* 
   Assume the data structure of the Google Spreadsheet is:
   NAME        COLOR
   ==================
   Apple       red
   Mango       yellow
*/


// define sheet url
var dataSheetUrl = 
'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/edit';

// open one of the sheet named 'Fruit'
var dataSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(dataSheetUrl).getSheetByName('Fruit');

// get sheet data
var data = dataSheet.getDataRange().getValues();

// loop through each row data and then log it 
for (var i = 1, j = data.length; i < j; i++) {
  Logger.log('NAME: ' + data[i][0]);
  Logger.log('AGE: ' + data[i][1]);
}
```